# Trimexcess on List(Of t) in .net

Tags: vb.net, list, methods, trim

After filling a list with the the needed strings, if the list won't be further appended, should trimexcess be called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `TrimExcess` after you load the list will likely save you some memory.  But remember that if the items in your list are of a reference type (and strings are reference types), then all you're saving is the memory required to hold the references.

So, for example, if you have a `List(of String)` that's allocated for 2,000 items and there are only 1,000 items in it, calling `TrimExcess` is going to save you the memory occupied by 1,000 references.  That's 4,000 bytes on the 32-bit runtime, and 8,000 bytes on the 64-bit runtime.

As Andrew Hare mentioned, calling `TrimExcess` after loading a list that's going to hang around in memory for a while is probably a good thing.  You might also consider calling `TrimExcess` if you remove a whole bunch of things from a list, and then you're going to keep the list around.  But calling `TrimExcess` repeatedly for the same list, unless it's really getting large, is just wasting time.

Answer (score 3):

You certainly can, but [keep in mind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132207(VS.80).aspx):

> This method can be used to minimize a
>   collection's memory overhead if no new
>   elements will be added to the
>   collection. *The cost of reallocating
>   and copying a large List can be
>   considerable, however, so the
>   TrimExcess method does nothing if the
>   list is at more than 90 percent of
>   capacity*.

I wouldn't worry too much about this unless you have found that large-allocated and sparsely-filled lists are taking up too much memory.

Comment: Say I have a few hundred lists in objects where each list has ~500-2000 strings of ~40 characters each. It wouldn't hurt to call trimexcess right?

Comment: It would depend how often you wanted to call it and the type of application. Would you call it 100s of times a minute, not really, would you call it after loading the lists out of a file once? Probably. Remember that lists doubles its size when it runs out of memory, so you would most likely gain something - but RAM is cheap, especially at even with ~8,000,000 characters...